# MATLAB: importing java libraries

Tags: java, matlab

I have the following lines in my MATLAB code:

```
javaaddpath('C:\Users\localadmin\SkyDrive\IdeaProjects\DrawModels\out\artifacts\DrawModels_jar\DrawModels.jar')
javaaddpath('C:\Users\localadmin\SkyDrive\IdeaProjects\DrawModels\out\artifacts\DrawModels_jar\itextpdf-5.4.1.jar')
```

I then go on to instantiate some JAVA objects defined in the files.

I would like to copy the JAR files to where the .m file sits, and then write the following instead (i.e. I want to use a relative path rather than an absolute one).

```
javaaddpath('DrawModels.jar')
javaaddpath('itextpdf-5.4.1.jar')
```

However, the MATLAB path doesn't seem to apply to **javaaddpath** and so the JAR files do not get loaded.

Any ideas as to how I may achieve a relative path addressing of JAR files?

The background for this is I want the MATLAB code to run both on Windows and Linux, i.e. whereever it is unpacked. The user may unpack it in any folder he chooses, so I don't want a hard-coded path in the source.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mfilename` to find the path of the running M file, which you can concatenate with the JAR file name like,

```
javaaddpath(fullfile(fileparts(mfilename('fullpath')),'DrawModels.jar'))
```

That must go in the M file with which you would like to add the Java class to MATLAB.